# Include in SELECT a column that isn't actually in the database laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to execute a SELECT statement that includes a column of a static string value. I know it in normal SQL query but how to do it in laravel query builder? I tried it as below...

```
select('uprn','client_job_number','apt_date','00:00:00 as apt_time','timeslot','created_at')
```

but not any success. I want apt_time as 00:00:00 as static in my data. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: do you have column name `00:00:00` on your table? and what if the name of your table

Comment: you were nearly there, the commas should be around `'00:00:00' as apt_time` not vs `'00:00:00 as apt_time'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DB::raw` method.

Try:

```
select('uprn',
       'client_job_number',
       'apt_date',
       'timeslot',
       'created_at', 
       DB::raw("'00:00:00' as apt_time")
      )
```

Comment: How do you pass a static value to the raw function?

Comment: @TheRealChx101 DB::raw is straightforward php method, which takes in a string argument. You can use an expression also (including the static value) as argument